# What is question mark "?" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For most of you most probably a trivial question...
What is the meaning of question mark in this code?

```
var pageQuery = parseInt(req.query.page);
var pageNumber = pageQuery ? pageQuery : 1;
```

If somebody could hand me over some reference also would be appreciated, as I could not find much about it.
Thank you.

Comment: ternary operator

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a ternary operator. Here's a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).